# Role-based read/write access in .NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to create this heirachy of access, where the rights are inheirited as we go down:

**Authenticated**: Can only make GET requests.
**Authenitcated w/role "employee"**: Also has write access to one specific controller.
**Authenitcated w/role "admin"**: Has read/write on every controller.

So far I have only encountered solutions where a custom policy will require certain roles. This policy is then applied to the controllers with: `[Authorize(Roles = "Role")]`. The problem with this solution is that I would have to add the "readonly" policy to all HttpGet actions, even if I globally require the admin role.

I want to remove the posibility of someone forgetting or accidentally removing an `[Authorize]` attribute on a controller.

I'm looking for a solution where a globally set policy would allow me to restrict access based on role and http verb. Somewhat like we do when setting up CORS, psudocode below:

```
var getPolicy = new RoleBasedPolicyBuilder()
    .AnyRole().AllowHttpMethod("GET");

var employeePolicy = new RoleBasedPolicyBuilder()
    .Role("employee").AllowController(EmployeeController);

var writePolicy = new RoleBasedPolicyBuilder()
    .Role("admin").AllowAnyHttpMethod();

o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(getPolicy));
o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(employeePolicy));
o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(writePolicy));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

First solution would work if you have roles even for read access.
Only other solution I could figure out by going through the documentation is to implement interface [IAsyncAuthorizationFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncauthorizationfilter?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

```
public class TestAuthorizeHandler : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string[] methodsThatDoNotRequireSpecialRoles =
    {
        "OPTIONS",
        "HEAD",
        "GET",
    };

    private const string PostMethod = "POST";

    public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // we don't need users to be authenticated for routes that contain this filter
        if (context.Filters.Any(filter => filter is IAllowAnonymousFilter))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var requestMethod = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;

        // we don't want to check authorization for the given methods
        if (methodsThatDoNotRequireSpecialRoles.Any(method => method == requestMethod))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        if (requestMethod == TestAuthorizeHandler.PostMethod && context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("MyWriteMethodRoles"))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Now in your `ConfigureServices(...)` function add a mvc filter

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc(options => {
      options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build()));
      options.Filters.Add(typeof(TestAuthorizeHandler));
   }
}
```

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies for more scenarios that could potentially work.

**Previous suggestion:**

Add a global filter that requires users to be authorized in your `ConfigureService(...)` function

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc(options => {
      options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
.AddRequirements(new RolesAuthorizationRequirement(new []{ "role1", "role2"}))
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build()));
   });
}
```

Now every controller path needs to be authorized with one of your roles. If you need some endpoint to have specific roles you will still have to set that. If you don't want that for some route, you will just add `[AllowAnonymous]` to a controller or a specific endpoint function.

Comment: But with this I only ensure that a user must have a role to have R/W access. I would still have to add `[AllowAnonymous]` to every `[HttpGet]` request?

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the question, thought you also have read-role :) looking for something else now as solution.

Comment: Currently testing this solution. Right now I'm getting the 403, even after successfully authenticating with `await context.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Bearer")`. What is the `ChallengeResult("Bearer");` supposed to return? Cause right now I'm just getting a list with a single string: "Bearer" in it...

Comment: If you are still getting a 403 I think you don't return a proper claimsprinciapl like new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Bearer")); but it could be smth different. You will have to dig into it to make it work with your authentication system. What are you using? IdentityServer?

Comment: JWT Bearer tokens with Azure AD.

Comment: I updated the post and tested it with basic authentication. The initial authorizationhandler is processed and then the custom one kicks in. This way it works for me, I get 403 with post request, bc I am not in the given role. Allow anoynmous requests are skipped.